# How is using SQLAlchemy different in Flask framework

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I've written things in SQLAlchemy that work fine but the same workflow/commands seem to be askew when doing them in Flask. For example, these types of lines are getting flagged as "undefined":

```
metadata = MetaData(db)

abc = Table('abc', metadata, autoload=True)

s = select([abc.name])
```

I do have **from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy** at the top.

Is there something else I need to be doing additionally or instead?

(For reference, I'm running it at pythonanywhere)

Comment: have you installed SQLAlchemy in your virtual environment ?

Comment: This behavior is clearly due to attempting to treat `flask_sqlachemy` as though it were "native" or "real" `sqlalchemy` when it clearly isn't. Nowhere in the [`flask_sqlachemy` documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/) is the code you use recommended or documented. I agree it would be helpful if the differences were explicitly flagged - I made just the same mistake when I first used Flask.

Answer (score 3):

Importing `SQLAlchemy` will not give you direct access to the names inside that module. You should also be aware that using the `flask_sqlalchemy` (formerly `flask.ext.sqlalchemy`) module uses a somewhat different mechanism to access SQLAlchemy features. This means that any attempt to transfer your current knowledge of `SQLAlchemy` shouold be informed by a study of the [`flask_sqlalchemy` documentation](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/).

Typically you will create a Flask application and then pass that to a call to `SQLAlchemy` [as in this example](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/#a-minimal-application). The relevant code is shown below.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

The `db` object now has the `Model`, `Column` and the various datatypes as attributes, so you can define a table/model in the following way.

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username
```

I personally am not fond of this particular access model, since it forces me to qualify the various names inside the `db` namespace rather than simply importing them from a module and using them unqualified, but it seems to work (at least for relatively uncomplicated databases).

If you are an experienced SQLAlchemy user you might want to consider using the standard access mechanisms, though this may render you vulnerable to subtle bugs due to unanticipated thread/web session interactions. I have also heard that it can be tricky to deploy multiple databases. I have no direct evidence of this, so please regard it as anecdotal.